# How can I display a box by using the hover method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I display a box by using the hover method in jQuery?
I want to open my box by hovering the button like this one
[example](http://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/demo.html)

Comment: Please share your code till now whatever you tried.

Comment: You can use CSS for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanna use jQuery's hover function, there's a simple example below on how to show an element when hovering another. The idea is to add a class to the "box" when hovering the button, and then style that class in CSS. In this case, the box is hidden by default (`visibility: hidden;`), and when the class `visible` is added, the box will instead get the style `visibility: visible;`.

This however can be done with CSS only.

```js
$("#button1").hover(function(){
    $('#box1').addClass('visible');
},function(){
    $('#box1').removeClass('visible');
});
```

```css
#box1{
  margin-top: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
  position:relative;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.2s, top 0.2s;
}
#box1.visible{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" id="button1">Hover me</a>
<div id="box1">I'm a box</div>
```